# Diophantine Equatiοn $x^3=2^y+15$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I would like some help with the diophantine equation
$x^3=2^y+15$

I have tried working with last digits and modular arithmetic but that hasn't got me anywhere.

Comment: Why the interest in that particular equation?

Comment: I read it in a book.

Comment: So, it's an exercise in the book? What book? What page? What context? Sometimes, it helps to know these things, they give clues as to the intended method of solution.

Comment: $x^3 - 15$ must be divisible by 2, can you see that?

Comment: Also, $x$ must be odd as well

Comment: Yes its an exercise from a number theory book from my country. It is in the chapter "Diophantine equations"  and is among other similar problems which are quite easy. Therefore I think that there must be an elementary solution using divisibility and modular arithmetic.

Comment: Indeed, there is an elementary solution using modular arithmetic...

Comment: Yes Varun. x must also be of the form 16k-1 but I cant find a full solution.

Comment: Any hints fretty?

Comment: Which modulus have you tried?

Comment: I have tried 3,4,10 and 16

Comment: You might want to try $7$...

Comment: Thanks fretty. It was all about taking the right modulus after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tempting thing is to try a suitable power of $2$ as modulus. Then for $y$ large enough you are left solving $x^3 \equiv 15 \bmod 2^m$

However, since $3$ is coprime to $\phi(2^m) = 2^{m-1}$ you will always be able to solve this congruence. Hence working mod a power of $2$ does not tell you there are no solutions to this Diophantine.

This however gives you a clue to what modulus $n$ you might like to use. We need one such that hcf$(3,\phi(n)) \neq 1$. The first possibility is $n=7$ and this works...

(Of course for the purpose of the exercise you don't have to do everything I did above, you just need to stumble upon modulus $7$...however I thought I would explain the thought processes that might get someone more familiar with this stuff there).

Comment: Thanks for this nice explanation of the process.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** An unfairly neglected modulus is $7$.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, notice some things:

- $x^3 -15$ must be divisible by 2
- $x$ must be odd as well

Also, try and use the unit digits:

$2^y$ can end in:

$$2,4,6, 8$$

**Case 1: If it ends in 2**

Then,

$x^3$ ends in 7, which occurs if $x$ has a units digit of 3.

**Case 2: If it ends in 4**

Then,

$x^3$ ends in 9, which occurs if $x$ has a units digit of 9.

**Case 3: If it ends in 8**

$x^3$ ends in 3, which occurs if $x$ has a units digit of 7.

**Case 4: If it ends in 6**

$x^3$ ends in 1, which occurs if $x$ has a units digit of 1.

Therefore, we can conclude that $x$ follows the units digits of $3^n$.

**NOTE**

I haven't found a full solution yet, I'm just posting some hints to start you off.